# commons-net-3.1

Tags: java, apache-commons-net

Sorry if it is a stupid question, but I can't figure out how to do this...
I downloaded `commons-net-3.1` from [commons.apache.org](http://commons.apache.org/net/download_net.cgi) and I don't know how to have it in my Java System Library or anywhere else I can use it from. I need to use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.

Comment: which IDE are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Eclipse. Juno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be overkill for what you're trying to do, but please use a dependency management system instead of managing your dependencies manually. It's a bit more setup now, but you'll reap the rewards later (and anyone else working on your project will thank you).

Take a look at [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), for example.

Comment: I guess this is what I've been searching for. Thanks a lot. Though it is overkilling, because all I need is to use `FileUtils`, and to be honest, only one function of `FileUtils` :), because it is easier and far more efficient than other ways of copying files

Answer (score 1):

You need to import/add jar file to your project by browsing to downloaded/extracted binaries folder.

For example in Eclipse, right click on project -> build path -> libraries -> add external jar